# can I read the window screen buffer of telnet login to a text file?

Tags: windows, telnet

I have login to a telnet port where when I toggle a variable, bunch of logs wrap over the scren. I want to read the logs in telnet window to a text file after toggle, that is to read logs to text file for a particular instance. I there any command in windows OS or telnet?

Comment: Consider asking this at: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Putty provides screen capture and a configurable screen buffer size. If you are running a curses based application putty can capture the current screen but not what has been previously cleared by curses.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the information. I found the partial answer
telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  -f filepath redirects all the logs in screen to file but need to work on a different window. Thanks